Xtrabackup restore failing
I was running an xtrabackup  full backup restore, however while running restore; I’m getting below error message:
Any idea what’s wrong here? There’s no tablespace SDI or how can I avoid this error?
[ERROR] [MY-011825] [Xtrabackup] Failed to load table using tablespace SDI
2024-09-17T16:16:21.238974+02:00 0 [ERROR] [MY-011825] [Xtrabackup] innodb_init(): Error occured
2024-09-17T16:16:21.239164+02:00 0 [Note] [MY-011825] [Xtrabackup] xtrabackup --prepare generated new redo log files. Skipping rename from ib_redo0 to xtrabackup_logfile


your table space has not enough diskspace, have you checked the original size and see it it fits

Hi @nbk thanks for your response. There's no tablespace actually. But, I'm still getting this error

you need a a table space to create databases tables and so on, so the backup will have to create  one or use the default
